# 'type' object is not subscriptable mapping DataFrame

Tags: python, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to construct a complex schema structure (StructType) to map to a DataFrame while loading a JSON file, however I'm getting  an error

> **'type' object is not subscriptable**

Below is the piece of code I'm trying:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import StructField, StringType, IntegerType, StructType

baseshema = StructType[StructField('ID Number', StringType(), True),
              StructField('Entity Name', StringType(), True),
              StructField('Phone Number', StringType(), True),
            StructField('Address',StructType[StructField('Building', StringType(), True),
              StructField('Street', StringType(), True),
              StructField('City', StringType(), True),
              StructField('State', StringType(), True),
              StructField('Postcode', StringType(), True)]),
             StructField('Location',StructType[StructField('Latitude', StringType(), True),
              StructField('Longitude', StringType(), True),
              StructField('Location', StringType(), True)])]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use parentheses to call the constructor. Further, init takes one paramter, so you'll have to wrap the fields in a list. It should look like this:

```
baseshema = StructType([StructField('ID Number', StringType(), True),
                        StructField('Entity Name', StringType(), True),
                        StructField('Phone Number', StringType(), True),
                        StructField('Address',StructType([
                            StructField('Building', StringType(), True),
                            StructField('Street', StringType(), True),
                            StructField('City', StringType(), True),
                            StructField('State', StringType(), True),
                            StructField('Postcode', StringType(), True)])),
                        StructField('Location',StructType([
                            StructField('Latitude', StringType(), True),
                            StructField('Longitude', StringType(), True),
                            StructField('Location', StringType(), True)]))])
```